# rapidjson modifying document creating object and removing member causes assert when writing document

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have a bit of code where I parse a json file, edit it, and save it again. The code works fine as long as I don't create an object and then remove a member. Doing those two steps causes an assertion in the object where the member was removed when writing again. I've compiled a small example to show what I mean:

```cpp
#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1

#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/prettywriter.h"
#include "rapidjson/istreamwrapper.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    rapidjson::Document document;

    {
        std::ifstream file( "test.json" );
        rapidjson::IStreamWrapper file_wrapper( file );


        // Now load it up
        if( document.ParseStream( file_wrapper ).HasParseError() )
        {
            std::cout << "Configuration: Error parsing JSON." << std::endl;
            return( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    // Now move some things around
    {
        auto &allocator = document.GetAllocator();

        // Shorthand
        auto &one = document[ "one" ];

        // Move each
        if( one.HasMember( "fruit" ) and one[ "fruit" ].IsString() )
        {
            const std::string &s = one[ "fruit" ].GetString();

            document.AddMember( "fruit", s, allocator );

            one.RemoveMember( "fruit" );
        }
        if( one.HasMember( "pear" ) and one[ "pear" ].IsString() )
        {
            std::string s = one[ "pear" ].GetString();

            rapidjson::Value value( rapidjson::kObjectType );

            value.AddMember( "pear", s, allocator );

            document.AddMember( "sugar", std::move( value ), allocator );

            one.RemoveMember( "pear" );
        }
        if( one.HasMember( "apple" ) and one[ "apple" ].IsString() )
        {
            const std::string &s = one[ "apple" ].GetString();

            document.AddMember( "apple", s, allocator );

            one.RemoveMember( "apple" );
        }
    }

    // Write it out
    rapidjson::StringBuffer sb;
    rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer( sb );

    // Write from the document
    document.Accept( writer );

    // Open the file
    std::ofstream file( "test-out.json" );

    // Now write
    file << sb.GetString();
}
```

Parsing this test.json file:

```
{
    "one" : {
        "fruit": "box",
        "apple": "plane",
        "pear" : "quincy"
    },
    "two" : {
        "french" : "pub"
    }
}
```

Will produce this output

```
report: rapidjson/document.h:1878: bool rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Accept(Handler&) const [with Handler = rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<> > >; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `m->name.IsString()' failed.
Aborted
```

If I take out all of the one.RemoveMember( ... ) lines the code will work. If I remove the block about adding an object it will work. RemoveMember and adding an object can't seem to co-exist.

How can this be sorted out?

Here is a backtrace from gdb:

```
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7a65535 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7a6540f in __assert_fail_base (fmt=0x7ffff7bdeea8 "%s%s%s:%u: %s%sAssertion `%s' failed.\n%n", assertion=0x555555562181 "m->name.IsString()", file=0x55555556212c "rapidjson/document.h", line=1878, 
    function=<optimized out>) at assert.c:92
#3  0x00007ffff7a73852 in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x555555562181 "m->name.IsString()", file=0x55555556212c "rapidjson/document.h", line=1878, 
    function=0x555555564ec0 <rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::Accept<rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0u> >(rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0u>&) const::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__> "bool rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Accept(Handler&) const [with Handler = rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<> > >; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Al"...) at assert.c:101
#4  0x000055555555a22d in bool rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::Accept<rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0u> >(rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0u>&) const ()
#5  0x000055555555a2c5 in bool rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::Accept<rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0u> >(rapidjson::PrettyWriter<rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::CrtAllocator, 0u>&) const ()
#6  0x00005555555568df in main ()
```

Comment: Can you add a backtrace? Have you tried running the code in a debugger?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sure! I've added in a backtrace from gdb.